# Issue with Portfolio Optimization tool - IndexError

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to develop my own implementation of Porfolio Optimizer which I found here: https://pythonforfinance.net/2017/01/21/investment-portfolio-optimisation-with-python/

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#list of stocks in portfolio
stocks = ['AAPL','AMZN','MSFT','YHOO']
#download daily price data for each of the stocks in the portfolio
data = web.DataReader(stocks,data_source='yahoo',start='01/01/2010')['Adj Close']
data.sort_index(inplace=True)
#convert daily stock prices into daily returns
returns = data.pct_change()
#calculate mean daily return and covariance of daily returns
mean_daily_returns = returns.mean()
cov_matrix = returns.cov()
#set number of runs of random portfolio weights
num_portfolios = 25000
#set up array to hold results
#We have increased the size of the array to hold the weight values for each stock
results = np.zeros((4+len(stocks)-1,num_portfolios))
for i in xrange(num_portfolios):
    #select random weights for portfolio holdings
    weights = np.array(np.random.random(4))
    #rebalance weights to sum to 1
    weights /= np.sum(weights)

    #calculate portfolio return and volatility
    portfolio_return = np.sum(mean_daily_returns * weights) * 252
    portfolio_std_dev = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))) * np.sqrt(252)

    #store results in results array
    results[0,i] = portfolio_return
    results[1,i] = portfolio_std_dev
    #store Sharpe Ratio (return / volatility) - risk free rate element excluded for simplicity
    results[2,i] = results[0,i] / results[1,i]
    #iterate through the weight vector and add data to results array
    for j in range(len(weights)):
        results[j+3,i] = weights[j]
#convert results array to Pandas DataFrame
results_frame = pd.DataFrame(results.T,columns=['ret','stdev','sharpe',stocks[0],stocks[1],stocks[2],stocks[3]])
#locate position of portfolio with highest Sharpe Ratio
max_sharpe_port = results_frame.iloc[results_frame['sharpe'].idxmax()]
#locate positon of portfolio with minimum standard deviation
min_vol_port = results_frame.iloc[results_frame['stdev'].idxmin()]
#create scatter plot coloured by Sharpe Ratio
plt.scatter(results_frame.stdev,results_frame.ret,c=results_frame.sharpe,cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.xlabel('Volatility')
plt.ylabel('Returns')
plt.colorbar()
#plot red star to highlight position of portfolio with highest Sharpe Ratio
plt.scatter(max_sharpe_port[1],max_sharpe_port[0],marker=(5,1,0),color='r',s=1000)
#plot green star to highlight position of minimum variance portfolio
plt.scatter(min_vol_port[1],min_vol_port[0],marker=(5,1,0),color='g',s=1000)
```

When running this code I encounter the following IndexError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PythonTraining/Portfolio_analysis/test.py", line 72, in <module>
    results[j + 3 , i] = weights[j]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

The author of this code is not very responsive and I'm not able to troubleshoot by my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the author of this code and I replied to you within a day and a half of your comment being posted on the website. I have replied to you there FYI.

Below is a working version of the above code - n.b."YHOO" is not returning any prices from Yahoo Finance so you will have to remove or replace it.

The problem was being caused by setting up your "results" matrix to have the wrong dimensions - I have replaced the offending code by using

```
len(stocks)
```

to set the dimensions correctly for both the "weights" vector and the "results" matrix.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#list of stocks in portfolio
stocks = ['AAPL','AMZN','MSFT']#,'YHOO']
#download daily price data for each of the stocks in the portfolio
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 31)
data = pd.DataFrame([d.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)['Adj Close'] for ticker in stocks]).T
data.columns = stocks

#convert daily stock prices into daily returns
returns = data.pct_change()
#calculate mean daily return and covariance of daily returns
mean_daily_returns = returns.mean()
cov_matrix = returns.cov()
#set number of runs of random portfolio weights
num_portfolios = 25000
#set up array to hold results
#We have increased the size of the array to hold the weight values for each stock
results = np.zeros((3+len(stocks),num_portfolios))
for i in range(num_portfolios):
    #select random weights for portfolio holdings
    weights = np.array(np.random.random(len(stocks)))
    #rebalance weights to sum to 1
    weights /= np.sum(weights)

    #calculate portfolio return and volatility
    portfolio_return = np.sum(mean_daily_returns * weights) * 252
    portfolio_std_dev = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))) * np.sqrt(252)

    #store results in results array
    results[0,i] = portfolio_return
    results[1,i] = portfolio_std_dev
    #store Sharpe Ratio (return / volatility) - risk free rate element excluded for simplicity
    results[2,i] = results[0,i] / results[1,i]
    #iterate through the weight vector and add data to results array
    for j in range(len(weights)):
        results[j+3,i] = weights[j]
#convert results array to Pandas DataFrame
results_frame = pd.DataFrame(results.T,columns=['ret','stdev','sharpe'] + [ticker for ticker in stocks])
#locate position of portfolio with highest Sharpe Ratio
max_sharpe_port = results_frame.iloc[results_frame['sharpe'].idxmax()]
#locate positon of portfolio with minimum standard deviation
min_vol_port = results_frame.iloc[results_frame['stdev'].idxmin()]
#create scatter plot coloured by Sharpe Ratio
plt.scatter(results_frame.stdev,results_frame.ret,c=results_frame.sharpe,cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.xlabel('Volatility')
plt.ylabel('Returns')
plt.colorbar()
#plot red star to highlight position of portfolio with highest Sharpe Ratio
plt.scatter(max_sharpe_port[1],max_sharpe_port[0],marker=(5,1,0),color='r',s=1000)
#plot green star to highlight position of minimum variance portfolio
plt.scatter(min_vol_port[1],min_vol_port[0],marker=(5,1,0),color='g',s=1000)
```